# AFNetworking and Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking

I'm trying to get a JSON response using Swift.

I sniffed the request and response -> everything ok. However the return value is always `nil`.

```
let httpClient = AppDelegate.appDelegate().httpRequestOperationManager as AFHTTPRequestOperationManager;

let path = "/daten/wfs";
let query = "?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien:AMPELOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

func successBlock(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) {
    println("JSON: " + "\(responseObject)")
}

func errorBlock(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:NSError!) {
    println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

let urlString = "\(path)" + "/" + "\(query)"
println("urlString: " + httpClient.baseURL.absoluteString + urlString)
```

I also tried it this way:

```
httpClient.GET(urlString, parameters: nil,
    success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        println("Success")
        println("JSON: " + "\(responseObject)")
    },
    failure:{ (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        println("Failure")
    })
```

... But the `responseObject` always seems to be `nil`

**EDIT:**

Maybe the reason is the possible wrong initialisation in my `AppDelegate`:

```
var httpRequestOperationManager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager? // JAVA SERVER Client

class func appDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
}

func configureWebservice() {
    let requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    requestSerializer.setValue("1234567890", forHTTPHeaderField: "clientId")
    requestSerializer.setValue("Test", forHTTPHeaderField: "appName")
    requestSerializer.setValue("1.0.0", forHTTPHeaderField: "appVersion")

    let responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

    AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.sharedManager().enabled = true

    // ##### HTTP #####
    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://data.wien.gv.at");
    httpRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL: baseURL))

    httpRequestOperationManager!.requestSerializer = requestSerializer
    httpRequestOperationManager!.responseSerializer = responseSerializer
}
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I highly recommend you use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) instead of AFNetworking. It is the successor of AFNetworking completely rewritten in and for Swift.

Answer (score 8):

Swift is fully compatible with Objective-C code, so your problem is **not** connected with Swift itself. In `AFNetworking`, the `responseObject` **can** sometimes be `nil`. This includes cases, where:

- A `204 No Content` status code was returned,
- If output stream was set to write to file,
- If  the error during validation wasn't `NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData` (e.g. unacceptable content type)

Check out [#740](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/740) and [#1280](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1280) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the hint … it seems that my basic initialisation is wrong.
I have not yet figured out why. I add the information to my original post

Comment: It is a server related issue -> I tried an other URL and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use Swift's interoperability with Objective-C frameworks but now there is an official library out there, let's check it out:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

This library is written in native Swift, from the creator of AFNetworking. You will probably want to look for this kind of thing when moving to Swift. I tried it out and it's awesome, like its predecessor.

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpManager.sharedInstance.getNewestAppList("\(self.numberofPhoto)", offset: "0", device_type: "ios",search: self.strSearch, filter: self.strFilter, onCompletion: { (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        SwiftLoader.hide()
        self.showAlertWithMessage("\(error!.localizedFailureReason!)\n\(error!.localizedRecoverySuggestion!)")
    } else {
        SwiftLoader.hide()

        if responseObject!.valueForKey("status") as! NSString as String == "0" {
            self.showAlertWithMessage(responseObject!.valueForKey("message") as! NSString as String)
        } else {
            self.itemsArray =  responseObject!.valueForKey("data") as! NSArray
            print(self.itemsArray.count)
            self.tableCategoryDetailRef.reloadData()
        }
    }
})
```

---

```
import Foundation

typealias getResponse = (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> Void

class HttpManager: NSObject {

    var AFManager: AFURLSessionManager?
    var strUrl: NSString = "url"

    class var sharedInstance:HttpManager {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = HttpManager()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }

    // MARK: - Method
    func getCount(device_type:String, onCompletion: getResponse) -> Void {
        let post: String = "device_type=\(device_type)"
        let postData: NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!
        let postLength:NSString = String(postData.length)
        let configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        AFManager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)
        let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(strUrl)/count" as String)!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
        urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        urlRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.HTTPBody = postData

        let task =  AFManager?.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if response == nil {
                SwiftLoader.hide()
            } else {
                let responseDict:NSDictionary = response as! NSDictionary
                onCompletion(responseDict,error)
            }
        }

        task!.resume()
    }
}
```