# Returning data from a NSURLSession completionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c

The async nature of this is throwing me off.

I am creating a class that I can use in my app. In the class I have multiple URLs (a.com/A a.com/B etc) for multiple backend APIs. Lets call the class NwrkDriver

```
@implementation NwrkDriver: NSObject

// Data is already formatted into a JSON doc.
- (int)PostToServer:(NSString *)url WithData:(NSData *)postData
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] ];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    <snip> deleted code for readability </snip>
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest
     completionHandler         
     {
         // Handle response here
         // Where to put response obtained here?
     }];
    [uploadTask resume];
    return 0;
}

- (int) DoAPI_A_WithData: (NSData *)data AndResult: (NSData *)result
{
    NSString *url = "https://example.com/A";
    [ self PostToServer:url WithData:data];

    // How to populate results here? 
}

@end
```

I want to use this NwrkDriver in other classes in the code. So ideally if I want to do login I will create the login API call in the NwrkDriver class and call it with the appropriate data. So in the Login class

```
@implementation Login: NSObject
{
    - (int) doLogin
    {
        NwrkDriver *nwrk = [[NwrkDriver alloc] init] 
        NSData *req, *response;
        <snip> deleted code for readability </snip>
       [nwrk DoAPI_A_WithData:req AndResult: response];

       // Now parse the response which is JSON also
    }
 }
```

Looks like I am writing/thinking in terms of serial execution which this is not.

Because of the async nature of the NSURLSession, how do people handle calls like auth or just a simple reqeust/response to a backend? Do all of them have to async in nature? If so how do I go about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How return data from an HTTP request in Swift/Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784793/how-return-data-from-an-http-request-in-swift-objective-c)

Comment: Look at the *Related* column, there are a few solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes, all your network requests should be asynchronous.

Maybe it helps to imagine it like a row of dominoes with each request a domino, and the completion handler is what you use to push the next domino in the row.

Your `-DoAPI_A_WithData...` method hides the completion handler, that's why you are not seeing how it should work.

You could rework it like

```
- (int) doAPI_A_WithData: (NSData *)data onCompletion: (ResponseBlock)resultHandler
```

where you call the `resultHandler`, that does whatever you need with the response, from the task's `completionHandler`.